# Node JS - error when extends layout in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

If I understood, I can move some parts of template to parent-template using when I use Jade?

I try to move link to some js files to head section, that I use only with one part of website, but I get an error.

My layout.jade:

```
!!!
html(lang='en')
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/box.css')
    block scripts
  body
    ..
```

my index.jade (just for try, it will be in other file)

```
extends layout

block scripts
  script(src='myscriptfile.js')
div#sortable
  ..
```

and some part of node server:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index', 
    {title: 'My title',
    images: images}
  );
});
```

I switch this option true/false

```
app.set('view options', { pretty: true });
```

but still get an error:

```
Express
500 ReferenceError: E:\projekt/views/index.jade:13 11| 12| > 13| 14| body is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For some reason I recall body being in layout.jade as !=body. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 2):

In the `..` of your snippets, you're referencing a `body` variable that hasn't been defined. I'm guessing around line 13 of `index.jade`:

> ```
> 500 ReferenceError: E:\projekt/views/index.jade:13 11| 12| > 13| 14| ...
> ```

You'll either have to remove it from the view or define it in the view data:

```
res.render('index', 
    {title: 'My title',
    images: images,
    body: '...'}
);
```

---

Side note:

If you haven't upgraded to Express 3.x, you may want to ensure layouts are disabled:

```
app.set('view options', {
  layout: false,
  pretty: true
});
```

Inheritance and blocks are [meant to replace layouts](http://www.devthought.com/code/use-jade-blocks-not-layouts/), not work with them. As stated in [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x):

> Removed... the concept of a "layout" (template engine specific now)